# How to keep div from reloading while navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is rather simple, but I haven´t found a simple solution for it.
I would like keep one div element from reloading while navigating on other pages. So this one div element would be on the same spot and not to refresh, even when I´m going from page to page on my web pages. I have Soundcloud player in this div, which I want to keep from reloading. The idea is to keep it playing the same song while navigating trough other pages. The point is, everything else should be able to reload, while keeping this one div from not reloading.

How to do this in practise is my question?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish something like that would be to load the pages via ajax, instead of a full round trip to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you reload the whole page, then you reload the whole page and you can't keep part of it.

You can either:

- Use frames (obsolete) to display two pages at once
- Only ever display one page but use `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch new data from the server, DOM to change the content of the page (leaving that one div alone) and use the History API (`pushState` and friends) to map the changes you are making with JS to real URLs (which, when requested, cause the server to load a page which is the same as the one you have created with your client side JS modifications).

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look into single-page app frameworks, like Angular, to help you quickly establish that kind of front-end functionality you're looking for